# Cannot import into database SQL dump. How to fix this error?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to import SQL dump with database with phpMyAdmin. I see the following error:

`/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1231 - Variable 'foreign_key_checks' can't be set to the value of '1'`

How to fix it?

I tried to import database

Comment: Which version of MySQL ?

Comment: It seems to have been a bug in some old version. Currently version8.0 is returning this error when doing `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS='1';`  (note the single-quotes, which should not be there....)

Comment: I use the XAMPP last version. What should I do then?

Comment: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/#:~:text=XAMPP%20is%20a%20completely%20free%2C%20easy%20to%20install%20Apache%20distribution%20containing%20MariaDB%2C%20PHP%2C%20and%20Perl) is a collection of packages, Which version of MariaDB do you have installed?  And where is the SQL dump coming from ?